# NoClassDefFoundError for java core class using Proguard

Tags: java, android, ant, proguard, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on an Android app that integrates Tokbox's OpenTok java sdk. All was working well before I used proguard (I need to use proguard because I exceeded the dex limit).

During runtime, I encountered this error:

```
Could not find method javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary, referenced from method com.opentok.api.OpenTokSDK.generate_token
VFY: unable to resolve static method 39502: Ljavax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter;.parseBase64Binary (Ljava/lang/String;)[B
VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x003a
threadid=47: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4184c2a0)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at com.opentok.api.OpenTokSDK.generate_token(OpenTokSDK.java:58)
```

I found the missing Class inside `...Java/jre7/lib/rt.jar` so I tried including it in my `proguard.cfg` using:

```
-libraryjars "C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/rt.jar"
-keep class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter { *; }
```

but the error persists. I can also confirm that `DatatypeConverter` is not in `seeds.txt` nor in `obfuscated.jar`.

I also tried downloading `jaxb-api-2.2` and including it in the build but `Ant` complains about

```
[dx] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
[dx] when not building a core library.
```

So my question is, how do you tell proguard to keep a class located in `rt.jar`?

Here is my `proguard.cfg`:

```
#################################################################################################
# Standard Configuration for Android App
# See http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

# -libraryjars "C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/rt.jar"

# -optimizationpasses 2
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-verbose
-printseeds seeds.txt 
-printusage unused.txt 
-printmapping mapping.txt 
# -allowaccessmodification
# -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature
-keepdirectories
-repackageclasses ''

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# adding this in to preserve line numbers so that the stack traces
# can be remapped
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable


#################################################################################################
# For RoboSpice
# See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/robospice/xGLRbGkLwQU
#Request classes purged by Proguard as they are "empty", others are kept
-keep class com.limbocitizen.android.playground.model.**

#RoboSpice requests and Results must be kept as they are used by reflection via Jackson
-keepclassmembers class com.limbocitizen.android.playground.request.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
  public *** is*();
}


### XML SERIALIZER SETTINGS

-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* <fields>;
    @org.simpleframework.xml.* <init>(...);
}


### Json SERIALIZER SETTINGS
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.* <fields>;
    @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.* <init>(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

#################################################################################################
# For Actionbarsherlock
# See http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*


#################################################################################################
# My Code

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn biz.source_code.base64Coder.**
-dontwarn chesspresso.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn com.bst.**
-dontwarn com.bugsense.**
-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.youtube.player.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.gson.**
-dontwarn com.nostra13.**
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.**
-dontwarn com.opentok.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.pubnub.api.**
-dontwarn com.samsung.**
-dontwarn com.sun.istack.internal.**
-dontwarn com.sun.xml.internal.**
-dontwarn com.testflightapp.**
-dontwarn com.tokbox.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn java.nio.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn java.util.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn main.java.tokbox.org.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.pool.**
-dontwarn org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.msgpack.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.springframework.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.xml.sax.**
-dontwarn tokbox.org.**

-dontnote **ILicensingService

-keep class * extends com.samsung.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.content.Loader { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener { *; }
-keep class com.createsend.util.jersey.JsonProvider { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition { *; }
-keep class com.opentok.** { *; }
-keep class com.tokbox.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
-keep class com.samsung.** { *; }
-keep class javax.xml.** { *; }
-keep class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter { *; }
-keep class main.java.tokbox.org.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class org.osgi.framework.** { *; }
-keep class tokbox.org.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had included external libs and I just added this to my proguard config file

```
 -keep class com.opentok.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.opentok.**
```

or for Twitter4j.jar

```
 -keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
 -dontwarn twitter4j.**
```

Also, For your information, **I generally put .jar files in project's lib folder**

and then define them in proguard config file this way

```
#-injars bin/classes

#-injars libs

#-outjars bin/classes-processed.jar



-libraryjars <java.home>/jre/lib/rt.jar

-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/tools.jar

-libraryjars /libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
```

Comment: Hi RDC, I already did "-keep class com.opentok.** { *; }" and "-libraryjars <java.home>/jre/lib/rt.jar" (you can see it on my proguard.cfg). I also put each .jar file (except the rt.jar) in my project's lib folder.